# React button component asks for key props

Tags: reactjs, button, key

I've been coding a flexible button component where I pass some values by param (text, class, size, icon, and such) and when I do a condition (if it's a link or a button) before returning the HTML, it asks me for a key prop.
Why is it asking for a key prop if it's not a list. I'm not even going through any array to return the value.

**This is the React button component code:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./button.css";

import { Icon } from '../Icon/icon';

const buttonTypes = [
    "button",
    "a"
];

const buttonClasses = [
    "app-button",
    "app-button-filled",
    "app-button-outlined",
    "app-button-icon"
];

const buttonSizes = [
    "app-button-large",
    "app-button-icon-large"
];

export const Button = ({
    buttonIcon = {
        name: '',
        style: '',
        position: ''
    },
    buttonText,
    buttonType,
    buttonTarget,
    buttonHref,
    buttonOnClick,
    buttonClass,
    buttonSize
}) => {

    const checkClasses = () => {
        if(buttonClasses.includes(buttonClass)){
            return buttonClasses[0]+" "+buttonClass;
        } else {
            return buttonClasses[0];
        }
    }

    const checkSizes = () => {
        if(buttonSizes.includes(buttonSize)){
            return buttonSize;       
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    const checkTypes = () => {
        if(buttonTypes.includes(buttonType)){
            return buttonType;
        } else {
            return buttonTypes[0];
        }
    }

    const insertContent = () => {
        let content = [],
            iconTag = <Icon iconName={buttonIcon.name} iconStyle={buttonIcon.style} iconClass="app-button-svg" />;

        if(buttonClass === "app-button-icon"){
            content.push(iconTag);
        } else {
            if(buttonText){ content.push(<span className="app-button-text">{buttonText}</span>); }
            
            if(buttonIcon){
                if(buttonIcon.position === "left"){
                    content.unshift(iconTag);
                } else if(buttonIcon.position === "right" || buttonIcon.position !== "left") {
                    content.push(iconTag);
                }
            }
        }

        return content;
    }

    if(checkTypes() === "button"){
        return (<button className={`${checkClasses()} ${checkSizes()}`} onClick={buttonOnClick}>{insertContent()}</button>);
    } else if(checkTypes() === "a"){
        return (<a className={`${checkClasses()} ${checkSizes()}`} href={buttonHref} target={buttonTarget} >{insertContent()}</a>);
    }
}
```

**Warning code:**

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop | button.js:84
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition for this trigger is passing an array in the list of children.

You are doing this near the end:

```
return (<button className={`${checkClasses()} ${checkSizes()}`} onClick={buttonOnClick}>{insertContent()}</button>);
...
return (<a className={`${checkClasses()} ${checkSizes()}`} href={buttonHref} target={buttonTarget} >{insertContent()}</a>);
```

Your children here are the result of `insertContent()`, which returns an array. Because it returns an array, it triggers the warning because no keys are specified.

To solve this, you need to change the function `insertContent` to include keys on the elements it puts into the `content` array